# How to solve On change going into infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

[image]

```
 <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtp_arrival" runat="server"></telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
 <telerik:RadDateTimePicker ID="rdtp_departure" runat="server" ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="cng_departure"></telerik:RadDateTimePicker>
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="rnt_night" runat="server" Culture="en-US" DataType="System.Int32" DbValueFactor="1" LabelWidth="64px" MinValue="1" ShowSpinButtons="True" Width="100%" ClientEvents-OnValueChanged="inc_check">
    <NegativeStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <NumberFormat ZeroPattern="n"></NumberFormat>
    <DisabledStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

JS

```
function cng_departure() {
var datePicker11 = $find("<%= rdtp_arrival.ClientID %>");
var datePicker12 = $find("<%= rdtp_departure.ClientID %>");
var minutes = 1000 * 60;
var hours = minutes * 60;
var days = hours * 24;
var valueTbx = $find('<%=rnt_night.ClientID %>');
valueTbx.set_value(Math.ceil((datePicker12.get_selectedDate() - datePicker11.get_selectedDate()) / days));
}

function inc_check() {
     var datePicker1 = $find("<%= rdtp_arrival.ClientID %>");
     var datePicker2 = $find("<%= rdtp_departure.ClientID %>");
     var date = datePicker1.get_selectedDate();
     date.setDate(date.getDate() + parseInt($('#<%= rnt_night.ClientID %>').val()));
     datePicker2.set_selectedDate(date);
 }
```

When i increase night or change departure date it goes in a infinite loop which calls each other inc_check and cng_departure methods until site crashes.
if i remove onchange event from any one control it works properly.
what to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create JavaScript Function CalculateDateDifference(source, destination)
Now, Attach this function to both text boxes, in the page_init event, like below

```
 rdtp_departure.Attributes.Add("onblur", @"javascript:CalculateDateDifference('" 
                                                    +   rdtp_departure.ClientID + "','" 
                                                    + rnt_night.ClientID + "')");

 rdtp_departure.Attributes.Add("onblur", @"javascript:CalculateDateDifference('" 
                                                    + rnt_night.ClientID + "','" 
                                                    + rdtp_departure.ClientID + "')");
```

Now write the problem specific logic in that JavaScript function. Hopefully this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. When `rdtp_departure` is changed, it invokes `cng_departure`, because of this

   ```
   ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="cng_departure"
   ```
2. `cng_departure` changes `rnt_night` and so `inc_check` is invoked. Because `valueTbx` in `cng_departure` refers to `rnt_night` and `set_value` is called on it.
3. `inc_check` changes `rdtp_departure`. Because `datePicker2` refers to `rdtp_departure` and `set_selectedDate` is called on it. So, again steps from 1 to 3 are performed.

That is why the code runs infinitely.